# And all the people said…

Tags: code-golf, string

**Objective** Given an input of text that does not contain characters `[` or `]`, perform the following actions:

1. For every instance of `Amen` with at least one capital letter (so all instances of `Amen` excluding `amen`), output that same `Amen` (retain capitalization).
2. For every instance of `/all the people said[?: ]/i` (that's a Regular Expression), also output `Amen` (any case is fine.)

After every output, you may choose any *constant* separator, e.g. a newline, space, or nothing.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program in bytes wins.

## Example IOs

```
Input: I said AMEN! AMEN, PEOPLE!
Output: AMENAMEN         ; any separator is fine, I choose none.

Input: amen amen amen amen
Output:                  ; nothing

Input:                   ; empty
Output:                  ; nothing

Input: *blah blah blah* And all the people said?
Output: Amen

Input: all the people said:
Output: Amen

Input: AMEN AMeN AmeN aMEN amen AmEn
Output: AMEN AMeN AmeN aMEN AmEn

Input: All the people said Amen! And all the people said AMEN!
Output: Amen Amen Amen AMEN

Input: LAMEN! Amen.
Output: AMEN Amen

Input: AmenAmenAmenAmenAMENamen
Output: Amen Amen Amen Amen AMEN

Input: And he was like, "Amen", then we were all like, "Amen, bruh."
Output: Amen Amen

Input: And all the aMen people said.
Output: aMen
```

### Bonus

- **-20 bytes** if you can "grab" the punctuation that follows the `Amen`, i.e., `Amen! => Amen!`, `AmEN. => AmEN.`, `I said Amen, bruh. => Amen,`, and `AMEN!!!! => AMEN!!!!`. `!` is the only character to be preserved multiple times. `.?!,` are the only characters to be preserved thus.
- **-40 bytes** if, there is an instance of `amen`, output, `Heresy! at index [i]` instead of nothing, where `[i]` is the index of the offending word i.e. `amen`.

#### Bonus IOs

Input and output is of the form `input => output`. (Separator here is a space.)

```
BONUS 1
Can I get an Amen! => Amen!
AMEN! and AMEN! and a final Amen... => AMEN! AMEN! Amen.
Amen? Amen, and amEn! => Amen? Amen, amEn!

BONUS 2
The man sighed and said, "amen," and left. It's AMEN! => Heresy! at index [26] AMEN!
```

### Leaderboards

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=64109,OVERRIDE_USER=8478;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?([-\d.]+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Do the `amen`s have to be in order?

Comment: @ZachGates Yes.

Comment: How do you determine the "index of the offending phrase"?

Comment: @ZachGates To be the index of the `a` in `amen`. E.g., `G amen => 2`, if your language is zero-indexed; 3 if it is one-indexed.

Comment: `AMEN!!!! => AMEN!!!!` and yet `and a final Amen... => Amen.`?

Comment: What if amen is part of another word ?

Comment: You match it anyhow @User112638726.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 37 bytes

```
S`amen
i`all the people said[?: ]
amenx
!i`amen([.,?]|!*)
```

The code if **57 bytes** long and qualifies for the **-20 bytes** bonus. [Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=U2BhbWVuCmlgYWxsIHRoZSBwZW9wbGUgc2FpZFs_OiBdCmFtZW54CiFpYGFtZW4oWy4sP118ISop&input=QWxsIHRoZSBwZW9wbGUgc2FpZCBBbWVuISBBbmQgYWxsIHRoZSBwZW9wbGUgc2FpZCBBTUVOIQ==http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=U2BhbWVuCmlgYWxsIHRoZSBwZW9wbGUgc2FpZFs_OiBdCmFtZW54CiFpYGFtZW4oWy4sP118ISop&input=QWxsIHRoZSBwZW9wbGUgc2FpZCBBbWVuISBBbmQgYWxsIHRoZSBwZW9wbGUgc2FpZCBBTUVOIQ==)

*Thanks to @MartinBüttner for porting [my Perl answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64122) to Retina!*

#### How it works

```
S`                          Split the input at...
  amen                      matches of "amen".
i`                          Case-insensitively search for
  all the people said[?: ]  matches of "all the people said",
                            followed by '?', ':' or ' '...
    amenx                   and replace them with "amenx"
!i`                         Print all case-insensitive matches of...
  amen([.,?]|!*)            "amen", followed either by a single '.',
                            ',' or '?', or by 0 or more '!'s.
```

Comment: May I use your `([.,?]|!*)` punctuation match pattern for my answer? I saw it and couldn't unsee it (and I certainly couldn't find a better solution!). It's certainly not going to beat yours :), but I don't want to plagiarize, and I'm not totally sure of the etiquette for borrowing solutions to sub-problems like this.

Comment: @apsillers Legally, all content here is licensed as CC-BY-SA, meaning that you can use it freely with attribution. Morally, porting somebody's solution to another language to outgolf him is more or less frowned upon, but taking a tiny part of somebody's answer is always fine.

Answer (score 7):

## VBA, 193 bytes

```
Function v(b)
For i=1 To Len(b)
If StrConv(Mid(b,i,19),2) Like "all the people said" Then v=v& "Amen"
q=Mid(b,i,4):k="amen"
If StrConv(q,2) Like k And Not q Like k Then v=v& q
Next
End Function
```

No Separation, No Regex, No Bonus. Had a version that got both Bonus but was MUCH longer.

Comment: You van lose 1 byte byte by changing `for i=1 to` to `for i=1To`

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, 51 bytes

```
s/amen/x/g;s/all the people said[?: ]/amenx/ig;say/amen[.,?]|amen!*/ig
```

The actual source code contains **70 bytes**, it must be run with `perl -nE` (**+1 byte**), and it qualifies for the **-20 bytes** bonus.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 155 bytes

```
from re import*
F,m=findall,"((?i)amen)"
for i in split(m,input()):
 if F("((?i)all the people said[?: ])",i):print'AMen'
 elif F(m,i)and i!="amen":print i
```

---

#### Example

```
$ python2 test.py
"All the people said Amen! And all the people said AMEN!"
AMen
Amen
AMen
AMEN
```

Answer (score 3):

### grep and sed, <strike>85</strike> <strike>83</strike> <strike>84</strike> 77 - 20 = 57 bytes

```
sed 's/all the people said[?: ]/Amenx/ig'|grep -oi 'amen[.,!?]*'|grep \[AMEN]
```

Comment: This will print `Amen?` for the input `all the people said??`. The best workaround I could find was to replace the string with `Amenx`.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis, I've used your workaround and updated the score.

Comment: This will print `amen.` for the input `amen.`. Fixing this will shorten your answer: just change `grep -v '^[amen]*$'` to `grep \[AMEN]`.

Comment: @hvd: You're right, this is much better :-)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript, 88 bytes

108 bytes - 20 bytes (catches punctuation)

```
alert(prompt().replace(/amen/g,' ').replace(/all the people said[?: ]/ig,'Amen').match(/amen(\??!?\.?)+/ig))
```

Comment: This prints `Amen?!.` for input `Amen?!.`, and `Amen!` for input `Amen!!!`.

Comment: @Dennis Sorry, didn't think about multiple punctuation marks being used at once, I'll fix it.

Comment: @Dennis Just fixed it.

Comment: @apsillers Didn't notice that either. I'll try to fix it later.

Comment: @apsillers Fixed

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 103 - 60 = 43 bytes

```perl
#!perl -p
s/amen/Heresy! at index [@-]/g;s/all the people said[?: ]/Amen /gi;s/(amen([.,?]|!*)|h[^h]+\])\K|.//gi
```

Counting the shebang as one, input is taken from stdin. Maintains punctuation for *-20* bytes, and identifies heresy for *-40*.

---

**Sample Usage**

```perl
$ echo amen amen, and all the people said?? amen amen | perl amen.pl
Heresy! at index [0]Heresy! at index [5]AmenHeresy! at index [37]Heresy! at index [42]

$ echo AMEN AMeN AmeN aMEN amen AmEn | perl amen.pl
AMENAMeNAmeNaMENHeresy! at index [20]AmEn

$ echo The man sighed and said, "amen," and left. It's AMEN! | perl amen.pl
Heresy! at index [26]AMEN!
```

---

## Perl, 70 - 20 = 50 bytes

```perl
#!perl -p
s/all the people said[?: ]/Amen /gi;s/amen|(?i:amen([.,?]|!*))\K|.//g
```

Counting the shebang as one, input is taken from stdin. Maintains punctuation for *-20* bytes.

---

**Sample Usage**

```perl
$ echo All the people said Amen, and all the people said AMEN!! | perl primo-amen.pl
AmenAmen,AmenAMEN!!
```

Comment: Your first solution fails for input like `ha]`. (Nevermind, just saw the OP's comment that the input can't contain square brackets...this question has morphed so many times I can't keep track.)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I don't think the OP has answered that question.

Comment: @Dennis Ah, you're right. Yet another unknown.

Answer (score 3):

## , 66 - 20 = 46 chars / 80 - 20 = 60 bytes

```
ïċ/all the people said[?: ]⍀,`Amen”ċ(/amen⌿,`x”ĉ/amen(\??!?\.?)+⍀)
```

[Try it here](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=false&input=Amen&code=%C3%AF%C4%8B%2Fall%20the%20people%20said[%3F%3A%20]%E2%8D%80%2C%60Amen%E2%80%9D%C4%8B%28%2Famen%E2%8C%BF%2C%60x%E2%80%9D%C4%89%2Famen%28%5C%3F%3F!%3F%5C.%3F%29%2B%E2%8D%80%29) - Firefox only.

First time here at PPCGSE. Hope this golf is pretty good.

EDIT: Actually, I'm beating CJam (in char count), so that's pretty good!

Comment: Yay, someone's using my language! Not bad for your first post.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 57 bytes

```
 q_,,\f{\:I>_4<_el"amen":A=*_A="Heresy! at index ["I+']+@?oK<)"?: "&,*el"all the people said"=A*o}
```

The code is **97 bytes** long and qualifies for the **-40 bytes** bonus.

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q_%2C%2C%5Cf%7B%5C%3AI%3E_4%3C_el%22amen%22%3AA%3D*_A%3D%22Heresy!%20at%20index%20%5B%22I%2B'%5D%2B%40%3FoK%3C)%22%3F%3A%20%22%26%2C*el%22all%20the%20people%20said%22%3DA*o%7D&input=AMEN%20AMeN%20AmeN%20aMEN%20amen%20AmEn).

Comment: CJam is longer than Perl? o_O

Comment: CJam doesn't have regular expressions, so that's not at all surprising.

Comment: Ohhh... *writes that down*

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, 100 bytes

```
alert(prompt().replace(/all the people said[?: ]/ig,'Amen').replace(/amen/g,'x').match(/amen/ig));
```

Comment: You can use `x=prompt();` and you can use also `alert(prompt().replace(...).replace(...).match)`

Comment: Done. Now it's 100 chars long.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>136</s> 135 - 40 - 20 = 75 bytes

```
alert(prompt(A="ameN").replace(/all the people said[?: ]|(amen)([.,?]|!*)|./ig,(v,a,p,i)=>a?a>A?`Heresy! at index [${i}]`:v:v[1]?A:""))
```

Explanation:

This code is driven by a three-part regex that feeds results into a [`replace` callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). The parts are:

- `all the people said[?: ]` - simply matches the required `all the people said` pattern
- `(amen)([.,?]|!*)` - matches any-case `amen` and punctuation (one of `.,?` or zero or more `!`, which makes the punctuation optional) into separate match groups -- credit to [Dennis for the punctuation pattern](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64128)
- `.` - matches any other character, not part of the above patterns, one at the time

Therefore, any match must either be an all-the-people string, an Amen match with optional punctuation, or a single character not part of either of those phrases. We use logic in the replacer callback to save and replace the appropriate parts of the string, and change every other character to the empty string.

```
alert(
  // store "ameN" in `A` and then prompt
  prompt(A="ameN")
    .replace(
      // three-part regex:
      /all the people said[?: ]|(amen)([.,?]|!*)|./ig,

      // replacer callback, with arguments
      //   v - total match
      //   a - "amen" match group
      //   p - punctuation match group (unused)
      //   i - index of match
     (v,a,p,i)=>
        a?           // if there is an Amen match
          a>A?      //   if the Amen is lowercase (lexically more than "ameN")
               `Heresy! at index [${i}]`
              :v     //   otherwise, output full Amen with punctuation
         :v[1]?      // if there is no Amen, but more than one character
          A          //   this must be all-the-people; output "ameN"
         :""         // otherwise, not an Amen or all-the-people
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 191 - 40 = 151 bytes

```
i=input()
a='amen'
for j in range(len(i)):
 s=i[j:j+20];w=s[:4]
 if s[:-1].lower()=="all the people said"and s[-1]in'?: ':print a
 if w.lower()==a:print'Heresy! at index[%d]'%j if w==a else w
```

No regex, and Bonus 2